# Bootstrap drag and drop with swapping functionality

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, drag-and-drop

I am searching for bootstrap drag and drop of list item in the page. But I am unable to search for the same. Using jquery we can do that we can get the jquery pluggin but I want to have bootstrap drag and drop functionality. Can we do drag and drop with swapping of listitem in bootstrap. If not then any solution? Your comment and answer are heartly welcome.

Comment: I think there is no such functionality in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap doesn't come with drag and drop functionality yet.You can use jquery UI draggable interaction.

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/